# Get device info and connected stations on AirOS 10 device (Ubiquiti airFibre)

Tags: ubiquiti, unifi

I am using an airFibre 60xR which is an AirOS 10 device and I am trying to get the device information and connected stations using the various suggested commands but none is working correctly.

On an airmax device I used `info` for the device information and `wstalist` for the connected stations and they worked perfectly well. Any ideas on the AirOS 10?